# Enabling full screen at runtime from fragment not working with devices having notch

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-windowmanager

Full screen mode is working for devices without notch with the following code.

```
            requireActivity().window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
```

For devices with notch I have set

```
            requireActivity().window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES
            requireActivity().window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
```

This works as expected if I am calling this code in `onCreateView()`. But if I call the same code after some delay using `Handler` then the bottom navigation hides (as expected) and the status bar also hides (as expected) but leaves black rectangle in it's place (may be a letterbox).

I have fixed the issue by using

```
            requireActivity().window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS)
```

So my question is Why is this the case. Why do I have to set `FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`. I am trying to understand some internals about how android uses and manages windows.

In my opinion the above mention behavior may be due to window not recomputing it's layout when I set fullscreen after certain time but IDK.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your assumption seems to be correct. You don't even need to wait a specific time. Calling the code in onViewCreated yields the same result.

Answer (score 0):

set statusBarColor to transparent

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION

window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

This in case if you need statusBar on top of your app